# FluentValidation Improperly Validating Model from DropDown

Tags: c#, model, asp.net-mvc-5, fluentvalidation

I have the following two models (stripped to relevant parts):

Models\Department.cs:

```
public class DepartmentValidator : AbstractValidator<Department> {
    public DepartmentValidator() {
        RuleFor(d => d.Name)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("You must specify a name.")
            .Length(0, 256).WithMessage("The name cannot exceed 256 characters in length.");
    }
}

[Validator(typeof(DepartmentValidator))]
public class Department {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar")]
    [MaxLength(256)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Models\FacultyMember.cs:

```
public class FacultyValidator : AbstractValidator<FacultyMember> {
    public FacultyValidator() {
        RuleFor(f => f.Name)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("You must specify a name.")
            .Length(0, 64).WithMessage("The name cannot exceed 64 characters in length.");
    }
}

[Validator(typeof(FacultyValidator))]
public class FacultyMember {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "nvarchar")]
    [MaxLength(64)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Department> Departments { get; set; }

    public FacultyMember() {
        Departments = new HashSet<Department>();
    }
}
```

I have the following controller code:

Controllers\FacultyController.cs:

```
// GET: Faculty/Create
public ActionResult Create() {
    // Get Departments.
    var departmentList = db.Departments.ToList().Select(department => new SelectListItem {
        Value = department.Id.ToString(),
        Text = department.Name
    }).ToList();

    ViewBag.DepartmentList = departmentList;

    var facultyMember = new FacultyMember();
    facultyMember.Departments.Add(new Department()); // Create a single dropdown for a department to start out.
    return View(facultyMember);
}

// POST: Faculty/Create
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,Departments")] FacultyMember facultyMember) {
    // Get Departments.
    var departmentList = db.Departments.ToList().Select(department => new SelectListItem {
        Value = department.Id.ToString(),
        Text = department.Name
    }).ToList();

    ViewBag.DepartmentList = departmentList;

    if (!ModelState.IsValid) { // Problem here...
        return View(facultyMember);
    }

    db.Faculty.Add(facultyMember);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Views\Faculty\Create.cshtml:

```
...

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Departments, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Departments, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Departments, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

...
```

Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\Department.cshtml:

```
@model MyProject.Models.Department

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Id, ViewBag.DepartmentList as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, "Select...", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

So, when I navigate to the create faculty page, everything displays properly; the 'Departments' field has a dropdown list with the departments in my database. However, upon submitting the form, my model state is invalid (see comment in code above). Upon further inspection, it seems that FluentValidation is spitting out an error because my "Name" field is null. That's exactly what it should do when I'm creating/editing departments, but for this dropdown in faculty members, it shouldn't be validating the entire department, should it? The only thing the dropdown is sending back is the Id, as I've specified.

The only thing that this dropdown sends is the Id of the department, which is properly received. So, what do I need to do to make this work? My goal is to have a dynamic set of dropdown lists, each populated with existing departments in the database. Similar to [this](http://www.itorian.com/2013/04/nested-collection-models-in-mvc-to-add.html) example.

Please let me know if anything else needs explaining.

Comment: You should be using a view model with a property `int SelectedDepartment` for your dropdownlist, not binding to a complex object. Your dropdownlist does not post back a value for `Department.Name` so `ModelState` will always be invalid.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I need to create a new class to represent this ViewModel, correct? And inside of it, I would just put all of the data that I required, including the regular faculty member fields and the selected department id/list? How would I handle a dynamic number of departments? Would my ViewModel just have an ICollection similar to my regular model, and then I loop through them and do a Find(id) on each one when the data is posted back?

Comment: Are you wanting so select multiple `Department`'s for a `FacultMember` (i.e. using ListBox or CheckedListBox) or just one `Department` for a `FacultyMember` using a DropDownList?

Comment: I want each faculty member to belong to one or more departments, depending on if the faculty member in question is full-time or part-time (an enum property I have within the FacultyMember model). So, my server-side validation would check if the faculty member is full time. If so, they can only have one department. Otherwise, they can have at least one. I could likely use some sort of listbox with a multi-select property, and then just validate the number of selected items server-side.

Comment: In that case your view model will need 2 'selection' properties - `int SelectedDepartment` and `int[] SelectedDepartments` and `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` DepartmentList` for the options. Then depending on the value of your `enum` property your would display either a dropdownlist or a listbox to select one (if full time) or one or more (if not full time). And you could apply a `RequiredIf` validation depending on the value of the enum.

Comment: Thanks, Stephen. Since the Full-Time/Part-Time selection is on the same form, I think I'll just show the user a ListBox no matter what, for simplicity. Then, I'll just return an error to them if they've selected an invalid combination (multiple departments & full-time). I'll get started on this ASAP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111260/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-kryzik).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution, as explained by Stephen Muecke, was to create a view model to represent all data I wanted to pass to the form and back.

ViewModel\FacultyMemberViewModel.cs:

```
public class FacultyMemberViewModelValidator : AbstractValidator<FacultyMemberViewModel> {
    public FacultyMemberViewModelValidator() {
        RuleFor(f => f.Name)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("You must specify a name.")
            .Length(0, 64).WithMessage("The name cannot exceed 64 characters in length.");

        RuleFor(s => s.SelectedDepartments)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("You must specify at least one department.")
    }
}

[Validator(typeof(FacultyMemberViewModelValidator))]
public class FacultyMemberViewModel {
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int[] SelectedDepartments { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("Departments")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DepartmentList { get; set; }
}
```

Views\Faculty\Create.cshtml:

```
...

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DepartmentList, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.SelectedDepartments, Model.DepartmentList, new { @class = "form-control" })             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedDepartments, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

...
```

Controllers\FacultyController.cs:

```
// GET: Faculty/Create
public ActionResult Create() {
    var facultyMemberViewModel = new FacultyMemberViewModel {
        DepartmentList = GetDepartmentList()
    };

    return View(facultyMemberViewModel);
}

// POST: Faculty/Create
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,Name,SelectedDepartments,DepartmentList")] FacultyMemberViewModel facultyMemberViewModel) {
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
        // Re-set the Department list.
        if (facultyMemberViewModel.DepartmentList == null) {
            facultyMemberViewModel.DepartmentList = GetDepartmentList();
        }

        return View(facultyMemberViewModel);
    }

    var facultyMember = new FacultyMember {
        Id = facultyMemberViewModel.Id,
        Name = facultyMemberViewModel.Name,
    };

    foreach (var departmentId in facultyMemberViewModel.SelectedDepartments) {
        // I'm assuming this is safe to do (aka the records exist in the database)...
        facultyMember.Departments.Add(db.Departments.Find(departmentId));
    }

    db.Faculty.Add(facultyMember);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```